# React setTimout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class Register extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: {
                email: "",
                confirmemail: ""
            },
            match: true
        };
    }
    handleChange = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            user: {
                ...this.state.user,
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value
            }
        });
        const value = event.target.value;
        const field = event.target.name;
        let match;
        if (field === "email") {
            match = value === this.state.user.confirmemail;
        } else {
            match = value === this.state.user.email;
        }
        setTimeout(() => {

            this.setState({
                match
            });
        }, 5000);
    };
    render(
        return(<div>{this.state.match && this.state.match ? (
                                    false
                                ) : (
                                    <div
                                        style={{ color: "red" }}
                                        className="error"
                                    >
                                        Email Doesn't match.
                                    </div>))}
```

Hello guys,
I have two inputs, and I am trying to add setTimeout Function to give time to user
to type he confirms email, but its take also 5 sec after I type confirm email to check its match.
so how can I improve that and make more practical?
I want it after I type first email its take time before checking it and while I type
didn't check till I finish typing and if I can make it faster in checking after stop typing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this?

```
 export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    matched: false,
    email: "",
    cemail: ""
  };
  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value }, () => {
      if (
        this.state.email !== "" &&
        this.state.cemail !== "" &&
        this.state.email === this.state.cemail
      ) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({ matched: true });
        }, 3000);
      }
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { email, cemail, matched } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter email"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          name="email"
          value={email}
        />
        <br />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Confirm email"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          name="cemail"
          value={cemail}
        />
        <h2>{matched ? "Matched your email" : ""}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Live working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-grothendieck-esdwt)

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeout; // declare the timeout
class Register extends Component {
    ...
    handleChange = event => {
        if(timeout) clearTimeout(timeout) // clear the timeout when the user is still typing
        ...
        timeout = setTimeout(() => { 
            this.setState({
                match
            });
        }, 2000); // reduce the time to wait to 2s for better UX
    };
    render(...)
}
```